# Is there a difference in performance for insertion of different elements in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, angularjs

My problem is the following:

I have a HTML document that uses a table to convey tabular information. Semantically all is well. But I'm afraid that it will grind my page to a halt, since this table will receive a lot of new information per second (something like 200 KB of text per second). Is there any performance difference between inserting a new DIV or a new table row?

I will be using AngularJS for the insertions.

Comment: The fact that you are inserting a lot of stuff per second is what's causing the grind there. What kind of data are you working on anyway?

Comment: it is a webchat application, sort of a Skype clone, if you like...

Comment: If you intend on allowing the user to scroll back through a very long list of chat history rendering the entire thing will likely be what slows down the browser.  You're probably best off doing some sort of virtualization (like in ng-grid) where only elements on screen are drawn and the "renderers" or DOM elements are re-used instead of being recreated constantly.  http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/ <- scrolled this one up to about 2000 rows and it's fine on my laptop, maybe an issue on mobile though.